# Non-blocking pasv sock and blocking connection (active) socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, fcntl

On my TCP server I would like to have:

1. non-blocking passive socket to have non-blocking accept();
2. after accepting connection I would like to perform some authentication like verifying client provided Id and Password. So I have well defined protocol and I would like to have blocking recv()/send() talk between TCP server and client via connection socket.
3. After client identity verification I would like to have non-blocking connection socket to enable server shutdown from external thread.

The problem is that when I firstly set non-blocking PASSIVE socket then accepted CONNECTION sockets are also non-blocking? Why aren't they separate sockets?

I have set passive socket to non-blocking mode using this code:

```
fcntl(ps_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

I do authentication through connection socket:

```
if((n_recv = recv(sock_fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0)) <= 0) { ... }
```

But here `recv()` doesn't block and client cannot deliver it's authentication id and password on the time before `EAGAIN` error.

Can I revert connection socket to be in blocking mode again, and passive socket left non-blocking?

Comment: This sounds very wrong ... don't block your whole service on a single client! Instead, use some context and a state machine. Also suggest `select()` (or something platform-specific like `epoll()`) instead of `O_NONBLOCK`

Comment: Yeah but they seems to inherit state from passive sockets and doesn't block :(

Comment: So put them into blocking mode. What's stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

The blocking-status is not inherited by accepted sockets in Linux. On BSD-derived systems (like macOS and probably Windows (though I can't find anything specified)) the non-blocking is inherited.

One solution is of course to make the accepted socket blocking again, and then non-blocking once the authentication phase is done. This will block the rest of the program if you're single-threaded, meaning you can't accept other connections while one user is authenticating.

Another possible solution is to use threads, or even processes, to handle connections.

*Or* you could use some polling like `select`, `poll` or if you're on Linux use `epoll` (or corresponding variants on BSD systems) to know when there is data to be received on the accepted socket. For this to work you could use a simple *state-machine*, where you have states like `WAITING_FOR_USERNAME`, `WAITING_FOR_PASSWORD` and `LOGGED_IN` etc.

Comment: @EJP You're right. The canonical BSD implementation lets non-blocking be inherited. Answer updated, keeping the viable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried such solution and it seems to work.

For me on OS X connection socket received from accept() on passive socket inherits its non-blocking mode. So after accept I am changing the connection socket mode to blocking one again.

Example code

```
    fcntl(ps_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    int cs_fd = accept(ps_fd); 
    // revert connection socket to non-blocking
    int opts = fcntl(cs_fd, F_GETFL);
    opts = opts & (~O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(cs_fd, F_SETFL, opts);

    // then authentication via cs_fd

    // after authentication change it to non-blocking again 
    fcntl(cs_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```